# Plotting points irrespective of X axis count in aChartEngine

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I used `MultipleTemperatureChart.java` for multiple **Y axis** chart,I plotted a sequence of 5 individual lines on **Y1 Axis** and 5 individual lines on **Y2 axis** with reference to **axis**

**X axis** contains 12 points similarly all **Y axis** also contains 12 points. These plotted lines are standard values Now I want to plot one more line on x&y axis which will contain only 3 or 4 points how to plot them. I Got stuck Here plz help me

I'm using `AChartEngine 1.2.0.jar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah I found the answer it was a very simple Logic,,,

and now

```
XYSeries SeperateY1  = new XYSeries("");
        SeperateY1.add(3.5, 70);
        SeperateY1.add(8,100);
        SeperateY1.add(14,130);
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = buildDataset(titles, x, values);
        dataset.addSeries(SeperateY1);
```

Then for Y2 axis,,

i Created two more Lists and added

```
Y2.add(new double[]{80,90,100});
    addXYSeries(dataset, new String[] { "" }, x2, Y2, 1);
```